# Queueable sits in "Processing" state then throws GACK: Salesforce System Error: Exception serializing: myNs.MyQueueableClass

Tags: queueable-apex

I've got a class with a finalizer, more or less like this:

```
public with sharing class queueableRepro implements Queueable, Finalizer {
    Set<Id> someIds = new Set<Id>();
    SomeClass someClass; // stores Database.SaveResult[], SObject[], Packaged_Object__c[] 
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        System.attachFinalizer(this);
        // do some queries and some DML
    }
    public void execute(FinalizerContext context) {
        // handle results from SomeClass - do some more DML
    }
}
```

However, once deployed in subscribers' production, it sometimes throws GACK `-1346727410` or `782332910` which with some help with Salesforce resolves to `Exception serializing: myNs.MyQueueableClass`.

I'm trying to figure out what could be the culprit. I have no way of repro, no actual logs and no premier support, lol.

My **guess** so far is this happens when **finaliser tries to serialise queueable instance** with either of the following:

1. SomeClass stores some unserialisable type (SavePoint, Exception - not sure is there's a full list somewhere).
2. SomeClass stores a circular reference which can't be serialised by JSON.
3. SomeClass stores some transient SObjectType (I've seen this before with Scheduled Apex - type such as SomeObject__Share would exist at instantiation of class, but not when apex scheduler picks up the job for execution causing failure without even a GACK).

Point 1 and 2 I wasn't actually able to reproduce - seems like queueable serialiser is actually capable to serialise exceptions and circular references!? Although with SavePoint's I get error: `Not Serializable: System.Savepoint` - slightly different. Point 3 more of a possibility, although as far as I looked we don't store any SObjectTypes...

EDIT: Found repro below

```
public with sharing class queueableRepro implements Queueable, Finalizer {
    List<Database.SaveResult> results = new List<Database.SaveResult>();
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        insert new Lead(LastName = 'foo', FirstName = 'foo', Company = 'foo', Email = 'foo@foo.com');
        System.attachFinalizer(this);
        results = Database.insert(new Lead[]{
            new Lead(LastName = 'foo', FirstName = 'foo', Company = 'foo', Email = 'foo@foo.com')
        }, false);
    }
    public void execute(FinalizerContext context) {

    }
}
```

Basically duplicate rule results don't want to be serialised. Here's sample results for that matter:

```
]|DEBUG|(Database.SaveResult[
  getErrors=(Database.DuplicateError[
    getDuplicateResult=Datacloud.DuplicateResult[
      getDuplicateRule=Standard_Lead_Duplicate_Rule;getDuplicateRuleEntityType=Lead;getErrorMessage=DuplicateAlert;getMatchResults=(Datacloud.MatchResult[
        getEntityType=Lead;getErrors=();getMatchEngine=FuzzyMatchEngine;getMatchRecords=(Datacloud.MatchRecord[
          getAdditionalInformation=();getFieldDiffs=(Datacloud.FieldDiff[
            getDifference=Same;getName=Company;
          ],
          Datacloud.FieldDiff[
            getDifference=Same;getName=Email;
          ],
          Datacloud.FieldDiff[
            getDifference=Same;getName=FirstName;
          ],
          Datacloud.FieldDiff[
            getDifference=Null;getName=Phone;
          ],
          Datacloud.FieldDiff[
            getDifference=Null;getName=Title;
          ],
          Datacloud.FieldDiff[
            getDifference=Null;getName=Street;
          ],
          Datacloud.FieldDiff[
            getDifference=Null;getName=PostalCode;
          ],
          Datacloud.FieldDiff[
            getDifference=Same;getName=LastName;
          ],
          Datacloud.FieldDiff[
            getDifference=Null;getName=City;
          ]);getMatchConfidence=100.0;getRecord=Lead: {
            LastModifiedDate=2021-08-0601: 11: 50,
            Company=foo,
            Email=foo@foo.com,
            OwnerId=005R0000009F9LLIA0,
            Id=00QR000000L9ognMAB,
            Name=foofoo
          };
        ]);getRule=Standard_Lead_Match_Rule_v1_0;getSize=1;isSuccess=true;
      ]);isAllowSave=true;
    ];
  ]);getId=null;isSuccess=false;
])
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to contact Support for the gack numbers, but I can definitely tell you that you cannot serialize `Database.SavePoint` or `Database.QueryLocator`. If there's any possibility of these kinds of entities, use `transient` so they can't be serialized. Circular references are not a problem with stored transactions, as they are not serialized in JSON (it's some kind of binary format that accepts circular references).

Comment: It was duplicate rules...

Comment: @dzh Oh, yeah, that would do it. There's a number of objects that are not serializable and must not be stored across transactions. Someday, maybe we'll get a list of them.

Comment: Thats really something that at least compiler should catch...